C long int always accesses memory as big endian?
In the comment discussion of an old unanswered question, a fellow user is claiming that the C long int type "accesses memory in big endian mode".
I apologize beforehand for my lack of experience, but the statement seems highly suspect. I was not able to find any information corroborating this via a brief Google excursion either.
At most this might be a specific compiler optimization technique, but it seems unlikely that this behavior would be strictly specified in the language design itself.
Please advise.

Big or little endianness depends on the hardware (CPU) the program runs on.

and hence the question. the user claiming this seems to be a highly ranked expert in C.

the comment  Doing *(long int*)memory will access the memory in the way long int accesses memory - in big endian. To print bytes, alias the memory with char and iterate over bytes.

check the prior comment: The machine is a big endian machine, therefore the latter comment explains specifically for that CPU

@mindoverflow  What CPU are you using?

there was no explicit mention in the comments that the talk was about the specific CPU itself.

@TedLyngmo i haven't checked, but i mainly read the comment as being a statement of fact

The linked question shows member a printed in least significant byte, so little-endian.

would my question be better received if it was "how i to-the-power in python pls"? i thought SO would still have computer science members rather than coders.

The OP was confused.  They though they were on a big endian machine but their output showed otherwise.  Likewise, it seems @KamilCuk was confused by OP's assertion.

i believe this is a valid question base on the comments of a high ranked user

@dbush thank you. people should learn from you on how to answer a simple question.

@mindoverflow Note the access performed in that question violates strict aliasing and is undefined behavior.  You can't in general trust the value printed out.

yes! i read you comment on there! thank you for coming by with the message. it is important.

The discussion you link to is about 64 bit access on a big endian machine - or at least the OP believe they are using a big endian machine. In that context, on a big endian machine (like a Power PC) then yes the long int type will be in the same big endian format as the CPU is expecting, naturally. That is what the comment is saying.

there we go. that's all the confirmation i needed. C is intricate. can't risk not verifying with experts

@mindoverflow I now posted an answer to that other old question too. Hopefully to clear out the confusion there.

thanks a ton. people like you are why its worth all the downvotes & closevotes to ask a question.

@mindoverflow You are quite welcome :) And yes we all tend to get our share of such votes around here, I'll blame them grumpy programmer types.

the votes leave me frustrated as they close my questions and revoke me from asking - i once got closed in minutes for asking what the need for classes were (apart from access control) if we could technically emulate them with structs... 5 years later came to find that structs in C++ were actually seen as classes. sometimes my inexperience wont let me google the right thing. i really wish theory questions were more well received.

Most computer languages are intricate, @mindoverflow.  And computers and computing environments are more diverse than you may appreciate.  But in this case, the basic answer to your question is simple: C implementations interpret memory in a way that is natural for the operating environment. And that's what the comment you refer to was saying.
